# Lookup value for column in df1 based column corresponding to matching value in df2 (Plz read body first)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

df1 looks like this

```
Co      Brand   Func    Acct
001     6001    3102    6201   
001     6001    3102    6201   
001     6001    3102    6213   
001     6001    3102    6223   
001     6001    3102    7689   
001     6001    3102    6201   
001     6001    3102    4026
```

df2 looks like this:

```
Acct    Group
4026    4MAS
4014    4MAS
4018    4MAS
6201    4MAS
6231    4MAS
```

**df1 has many duplicates and I don't want to drop them** I want my code to add a group column in df1 for whenever the Acct column matches. **If a record in the Acct field in df1 repeats multiple times I want to create a new record for Group in it each time.** I also want to rename it to 'Acct Group'. This is the code I've tried to use but won't work for me:

```
df1['Acct Group'] = df1.Acct.map(df2.set_index('Acct')['Group'])
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-2a28a01a9711> in <module>
----> 1 df1['Acct Group'] = df1.Acct.map(df2.set_index('Acct')['Group'])

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   3628         dtype: object
   3629         """
-> 3630         new_values = super()._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
   3631         return self._constructor(new_values, index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
   3632 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
   1119                 values = self.values
   1120 
-> 1121             indexer = mapper.index.get_indexer(values)
   1122             new_values = algorithms.take_1d(mapper._values, indexer)
   1123 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   2731 
   2732         if not self.is_unique:
-> 2733             raise InvalidIndexError(
   2734                 "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"
   2735             )

**InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects**
```

This is what I want the output (df1) to look like:

```
     Co    Brand   Func    Acct    Acct Group
    001     6001    3102    6201    4MAS
    001     6001    3102    6201    4MAS
    001     6001    3102    6213    B765
    001     6001    3102    6223    B765
    001     6001    3102    7689    B765
    001     6001    3102    6201    4MAS
    001     6001    3102    4026    4MAS
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

​

Comment: Your df2 has no matches in df1 at least the sample data you shared

Comment: @sammywemmy edited my question to reflect the matches. Sorry about that!

Comment: looks like a merge operation : ``df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates('Acct').rename(columns={"Group": "Acct Group"}), how = 'left')``

Answer (score 0):

The `InvalidIndexError` occurs because the index of `df2` has duplicate indexes. Thus when `df1` calls [pandas.Series.map()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), it doesn't know which index to choose if one of duplicate indexes matches.

`df2` looks like this:

```
Acct    Group
4026    4MAS
4014    4MAS
4018    4MAS
6201    4MAS
6201    4MAS
```

You can see there are two `6201` in `Acct` column. When you use `Acct` column as index by `df2.set_index('Acct')`, there are duplicate indexes.

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to drop duplicates in column `Acct` by:

```py
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Acct'])
```

Example code

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

DF1DATA = StringIO("""Co;Brand;Func;Acct
001; 6001;3102;6201
001; 6001;3102;6201
001; 6001;3102;6213
001; 6001;3102;6223
001; 6001;3102;7689
001; 6001;3102;6201
001; 6001;3102;4026
""")


DF2DATA = StringIO("""Acct;Group
4026;4MAS
4014;4MAS
4018;4MAS
6201;4MAS
6201;4MAS
""")

df1 = pd.read_csv(DF1DATA, sep=";")
df2 = pd.read_csv(DF2DATA, sep=";")

df1['Acct Group'] = df1.Acct.map(df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['Acct']).set_index('Acct')['Group'])

print(df1)
```

```
   Co  Brand  Func  Acct Acct Group
0   1   6001  3102  6201       4MAS
1   1   6001  3102  6201       4MAS
2   1   6001  3102  6213        NaN
3   1   6001  3102  6223        NaN
4   1   6001  3102  7689        NaN
5   1   6001  3102  6201       4MAS
6   1   6001  3102  4026       4MAS
```

The `NaN` value appears because there is no matching `Acct` of df1 in df2 from your example data.

Comment: Thank you, @Ynjxsjmh! Unfortunately, I am getting NaN values for all the records in the Acct Group when I print df1.

Comment: my apologies, the 'Acct' field in df2 has no duplicates. Just the Acct field in df1 does.

Comment: @Tanu If df2 has no duplicates, do you still get NaN values for all the records in the Acct Group of df1? If so, I have no idea what's going on unless I see the data.